# Change img src by clicking li item CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a ul of images and a main image. Is it possible to change the src of the main image by clicking one of the ul just by CSS?

Comment: No way man. You'll need to leverage the power javascript.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I've seen it happen somewhereI;m not quite sure how..I need build something that will run to browserws where users have disabled jaavascript

Comment: CSS can't handle click event handlers, the closest you'll get is using a pseudo state like `:hover` - but this has it's limitations as well since CSS can't select anything that precedes the initial selector and elements would have to nested in a very specific way. If users are still browsing the web with javascript disabled in this day and age then abandon all hope, ye who enter here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a ul of images and a main image. Is it possible to change the
>   src of the main image by clicking one of the ul just by CSS?

It ***is*** possible to achieve *something* approaching what you describe using just CSS.

You can take advantage of the fact that elements which have the `tabindex` attribute can take focus. Then you can use the `:focus` pseudo-class in your style rules.

However... it goes without saying: once you remove focus from the element which has it, the style rule invoking `:focus` will no longer have any effect.

**Working Example:**

```css
div, div img {
display: inline-block;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 0 0 2px;
padding: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}

.display-image {
position: relative;
margin-left: 12px;
vertical-align: top;
cursor: default;
}

.display-image img {
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
opacity: 0;
cursor: default;
transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}

div:nth-of-type(1):focus ~ .display-image img:nth-of-type(1),
div:nth-of-type(2):focus ~ .display-image img:nth-of-type(2),
div:nth-of-type(3):focus ~ .display-image img:nth-of-type(3),
div:nth-of-type(4):focus ~ .display-image img:nth-of-type(4),
div:nth-of-type(5):focus ~ .display-image img:nth-of-type(5) {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Click on any of the thumbnail images</h2>
<div tabindex="0"><img src="http://placekitten.com/205/205" /></div>
<div tabindex="0"><img src="http://placekitten.com/209/209/" /></div>
<div tabindex="0"><img src="http://placekitten.com/210/210/" /></div>
<div tabindex="0"><img src="http://placekitten.com/211/211/" /></div>
<div tabindex="0"><img src="http://placekitten.com/212/212/" /></div>

<div class="display-image">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/205/205" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/209/209/" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/210/210/" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/211/211/" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/212/212/" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you will need to use JavaScript for that.

In case you are using jQuery (UNTESTED)

```
$(document).on('click', '.ul-li-element-image', function() {
    $('.mainImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Try something along these lines...